# Compiling and Linking a C-Program for a 32-bit Architecture

Tags: c, architecture, makefile

So I'm working through an assignment for Stanford's CS107 course and I can't get past compiling the unfinished program (project files and the **original makefile** can be [found on the course page](http://see.stanford.edu/see/materials/icsppcs107/assignments.aspx), I'm working on assignment 4 RSS.)

After much research, I *think* the problem is I'm using gcc on a 64-bit architecture (Mac OS 10.6) and the pre-compiled library code under `assn-4-rss-news-search-lib/linux` is for a 32-bit architecture. I tried setting gcc to use i386 and -m36, but nothings working and I'm kind of just guessing.

So here's the output I get when I run `make`:

```
gcc  -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused-function    -c -o rss-news-search.o rss-news-search.c
gcc  rss-news-search.o -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused-function -g  -lnsl -lrssnews -L/Users/derp/Documents/OCW/CS107/Work/programming4/assn-4-rss-news-search-lib/linux -o rss-news-search
ld: library not found for -lnsl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rss-news-search] Error 1
```

Here's the output I get when I remove `-lnsl` where architecture differences are mentioned:

```
gcc  -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused-function    -c -o rss-news-search.o rss-news-search.c
gcc  rss-news-search.o -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -Wno-unused-function -g  -lrssnews -L/Users/derp/Documents/OCW/CS107/Work/programming4/assn-4-rss-news-search-lib/linux -o rss-news-search
ld: warning: in /Users/derp/Documents/OCW/CS107/Work/programming4/assn-4-rss-news-search-lib/linux/librssnews.a, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
Undefined symbols:
    "_URLConnectionDispose", referenced from:
        _ProcessFeed in rss-news-search.o
        _ParseArticle in rss-news-search.o
    ... several more undefined symbols mentioned ...
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [rss-news-search] Error 1
```

So I'm asking for any ideas on what I could do to resolve this. I've been at it for hours tweaking settings and Google'ing around to no avail.

Comment: can you compile c code period? Try writing hello world in c and trying to compile. I know that I've had some trouble with gcc and stdc lib on OSX so just make sure that's not it.

Comment: Use `-m32` if the respective tools and backend are installed. But here the problem does not seem to be directly related to that issue from the error messages ...

Comment: Yeah, I've actually written a ton of code in C for this course, but apparently assignment 4 and 6 are trouble spots. Usually the Makefiles are provided and work fine, but they were written with Stanford's Linux/Solaris machines in mind for the real, attending students.

Comment: is libnsl in the library path (presumably /usr/lib/ or /lib)?

Comment: In the `assn-4-rss-news-search-lib/linux` directory there is no libnsl.a, but there is a librssnews.a which is curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I'm pretty sure that using a precompiled library for linux on macos, whatever the bitness,  won't work (well, it is probably possible to cross-compile on MacOS for Linux and perhaps possible to run Linux executable in a compatibility box on MacOS, but that's quite different than what you are trying to do).
- libnsl is a standard library on Linux (it provides some networking related functions)

Comment: That makes sense. Would you suggest I dual-boot an OS like Ubuntu to finish this assignment then?

Comment: Dual boot or a virtual machine.  If you have one or the other already set up, switching doesn't make sense.  If you don't, a virtual machine has some advantages and is probably no more complex to set up if you have previous experience with neither.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone like me will be looking for answer after all this time passed...
Problem is easy solved by installing wubi version of 32bit Ubuntu. It works fine on 64bit system. You only need to edit makefile so it knows where to look for the libraries provided.

Comment: Vladmir, so then you cannot use a 64 bit system? Even if I'm on 12.10 Ubuntu x64?
I'm also pretty sure I don't have the .../cs107/lib libraries that states on Makefile. <sigh> I figured it out with assignment 2, but I don't think I'm up to this one.

Comment: As far as i know, those libraries are for 32-bit system. So in order to use them you want to have 32-bit system. Sorry for late response.